# How to correctly encode and decode geoJson that contains both arrays and objects in php

Tags: php, mysql, json, geojson

How do I correctly decode geoJson that contains both arrays and strings in php.
The problem I have is reading it from the database and converting back to json, the coordinates arrays are missing.

I am currently reading it from a (valid) geoJson.json file and storing it a mysql database using: $jsondata = json_decode($srcfile, true); Which works fine - it looks correct in the (mysql) database and still has the coordinates arrays intact.

The raw data looks like: (except there are 1000s of coordinates)

```
{
 "type": "Feature",
 "geometry": {
      "coordinates": [
           [
                [
                     [
                          -64.59727115377405,
                          60.30061384178721
                     ],
                     [
                          -64.52477086139639,
                          60.29980770242815
                     ]
                ]
           ],
           [
                [
                     [
                          -64.59727115377405,
                          60.30061384178721
                     ],
                     [
                          -64.52477086139639,
                          60.29980770242815
                     ]
                ]
           ]

      ],
      "type": "MultiPolygon"
 },
 "properties": {
      "prov_type": "province",
      "prov_code": "24",
      "prov_name_fr": "Qu\u00e9bec",
      "geo_point_2d": [
           53.3945173679,
           -71.7823138976
      ],
      "prov_name_en": "Quebec",
      "year": "2019",
      "prov_area_code": "CAN"
 }
```

}

When I extract it from the database and run json_encode($data) on it, the output looks like this - missing all the coordinates.

```
{
     "type":"Feature",
     "geometry":{
          "coordinates":,
          "type":"MultiPolygon"
     },
     "properties":{
          "prov_type":"province",
          "prov_code":"35",
          "prov_name_fr":"Ontario",
          "geo_point_2d":[50.4486575765,-86.0470011166],
          "prov_name_en":"Ontario",
          "year":"2019",
          "prov_area_code":"CAN"
     }
}
```

1. is there a better way to store it originally to make it easier to work with? (I'm using modx xpdo which does not seem to support the JSON database type in the model - it just converts it to longtext)

OR

2. what is the correct method of encoding it back into valid json with the coordinates intact?

**UPDATED - Added import method**

```
public function importGeodata()
    {

        // $srcfile = file_get_contents('/var/www/vhosts/mcgill.local/src/core/components/mcgill/data/provinces.json');

        $srcfile = file_get_contents('/var/www/vhosts/mcgill.local/src/core/components/mcgill/data/us-states.json');

        $jsondata = json_decode($srcfile, true);

        // echo '<pre>';print_r($jsondata); echo '</pre>'; 


        foreach($jsondata['features'] as $feature)
        {
            // $search = $feature['properties']['prov_name_en']; // FOR CANADA
            $search = $feature['properties']['NAME']; // FOR USA
            

            if(!$updateObj = $this->modx->getObject('CatalogStates', array('name' => $search)))
            {
                echo '<br>Could not find object: ' . $search;
            }else{
                echo '<br>Found  object: '.$search;

  
                $updateObj->set('feature', json_encode(array($feature)));

                if(!$updateObj->save())
                {
                    echo '<br>Error saving object: ' . $search;
                }

            }

        }

        return;

    }
```

**Retrieve data:**

```
public function getGeoJson()
      {

           $criteria = $this->modx->newQuery('CatalogStates');

           $criteria->where([
                'id:IN' => array(1,2),
           ]);

           if($states = $this->modx->getCollection('CatalogStates',$criteria)) // returns an array of objects
           {
                foreach($states as $state)
                {
                     $feature = $state->get('feature');
                     $coordinates = $feature['geometry']['coordinates'];
                     print_r($coordinates); // this returns the coordinates array
                     echo json_encode($coordinates); // this returns nothing!?
                }
           }
      }
```

Comment: 1. Show us the code that stores and retrieves the data. 2. Your 2 examples are completely different data. 3. Are you certain that the second example was correct _before_ being touched by your code?

Comment: I think you're doing it backwards. You'll want to json_encode before saving to the database and json_decode after retrieving. `$jsondata = file_get_contents($srcfile)` then save the json string to the db, because as it stands now you're saving the json array itself to the db rather than the string representation of it.

Comment: @admcfajn yes - you are correct, I have to decode the data to iterate through it so I can look for keys to match existing data in the database then I encode it back to store it.  Like I say, viewing the raw data in the database is correct (I can cut & paste it into a linter without errors)

Comment: @Sammitch The data is different (no matter) the structure is identical - but missing the coordinates multidimensional array.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a character-encoding issue? Maybe add the following `if (json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE) { printf("JSON Error: %s", json_last_error_msg()); }` after `echo json_encode($coordinates);` or use one of the [flags for the json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function to help debug &/or help resolve the issue.

Comment: the problem seems to be encoding the multiple empty nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Well, bizzarre, it was MODX that was  screwing me... MODX uses double square braces to denote code that should be processes or included - i.e.

[[code_snippet_name]]
[[*include_chunk_name]]

etc.

when it saw the coordinates structure:

```
"coordinates": [
       [
            [
                 [
                      -64.59727115377405,
                      60.30061384178721
                 ],
                 [
                      -64.52477086139639,
                      60.29980770242815
                 ]
            ]
       ],
       [
            [
                 [
                      -64.59727115377405,
                      60.30061384178721
                 ],
                 [
                      -64.52477086139639,
                      60.29980770242815
                 ]
            ]
       ]

  ]
```

It basically interpreted it as:

```
"coordinates": [[ // try to run a code snip here
            // run this code snip (and fail)
            [[-64.59727115377405,60.30061384178721], 
            // give up trying to output anything till we find a matching closing brace
```

So the actual solution is to:

```
json_encode($feature, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```